# getting all combinations from numbers without repeating

Tags: c++, visual-c++, permutation, visual-c++-2008

hi
I work with c++ ,can I find easy  way for getting an array from a set of numbers containing all possible combinations between 
ex : {1,2,3}

```
  { {3,1,2},
   {1,2,3},
   {3,2,1},
   {1,3,2},
   {2,1,3},
   {2,3,1}
  };
```

the problem if i get 5 or more numbers how to make there's 120 combination

Comment: What you're looking for is something called the "powerset" and thus this is a duplicate of [combinations algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506119/combinations-algorithm)

Comment: @Mark:  Based on the OP's example and numbers, I think he actually means _permutations_, not _combinations_.  (I'm certain there is a duplicate, but a quick 30 second search didn't yield one.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get all permutations of xPy in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663949/how-do-i-get-all-permutations-of-xpy-in-c)

Comment: @James, you're right, though I'm sure this is still a duplicate, but I must have the wrong one.

Answer (score 7):

Those are permutations, not combinations.

You can use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to compute all of the permutations of a sequence.  It will look something like this:

```
std::array<int, 3> data = { 1, 2, 3 };
do {
    // use current permutation
} while (std::next_permutation(data.begin(), data.end()));
```

(I've used `std::array` from C++0x for this example; you can also find the `array` container in C++ TR1 and in Boost.  This algorithm also works with any container that is bidirectionally iterable, like `std::vector`.)